# Setting plot background colour in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, seaborn

I am using Seaborn to plot some data in Pandas.

I am making some very large plots (`factorplot`s).

To see them, I am using some visualisation facilities at my university.
I am using a Compound screen made up of 4 by 4 monitors with small (but nonzero) bevel -- the gap between the screens. 
This gap is black.
To minimise the disconnect between the screen i want the graph backgound to be black.
I have been digging around the documentation and playing around and I can't work it out..
Surely this is simple.

I can get grey background using `set_style('darkgrid')`

do i need to access the plot in matplotlib directly?

Comment: `sns.set_style("whitegrid")` was what I looked for when I found this question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`seaborn.set` takes an `rc` argument that accepts a dictionary of valid matplotlib `rcparams`. So we need to set two things: the `axes.facecolor`, which is the color of the area where the data are drawn, and the `figure.facecolor`, which is the everything a part of the figure outside of the `axes` object.

**(edited with advice from @mwaskom)**

So if you do:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
seaborn.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'cornflowerblue', 'figure.facecolor':'cornflowerblue'})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

You get:

[image]

And that'll work with your `FacetGrid` as well.

Answer (score 11):

I am not familiar with seaborn but the following appears to let you change
the background by setting the axes background. It can set any of the `ax.set_*` 
elements.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=pd.DataFrame({'x':['1','1','2','2','13','13'],
                'y':np.random.randn(6)})

facet = sns.factorplot('x','y',data=m)

facet.set(axis_bgcolor='k')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well that works. 
I hope it isn't the best way.
(I suspect it is though).
I will wait to see if a seaborn expert has a better way before accepting this.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to set the theme:

```
seaborn.set_theme(style='white')
```

Answer (score 4):

In new versions of seaborn you can also use 
`axes_style()` and `set_style()` to quickly set the plot style to one of the predefined styles: **darkgrid, whitegrid, dark, white, ticks**

```
st = axes_style("whitegrid")
```

```
set_style("ticks", {"xtick.major.size": 8, "ytick.major.size": 8})
```

[More info in seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.axes_style.html)