# certain seaborn plot colors not displaying on projector

Tags: python, colors, project, seaborn

I often have to present my data analyses in meetings where we either use a projector or a large TV monitor, an example plot might look like this (generated with seaborn):

[image]

I've noticed that often times, certain colors will not show very well (if at all) on these displays, whereas it shows just find on my computer monitor.  For example, in this example, the gray background will not show at all.

Is there another set of colors I can use that are "safe" to use with projectors and TV monitors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is caused by bad contrasts or dynamic ranges of cheap projectors. By default, seaborn uses somewhat muted low-contrast color schemes because these are nicer to the eye.

You can use the function [`seaborn.set_palette`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html) to change the colors used.

The seaborn documentation has a nice page about [color palettes](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) that explains how to create different color schemes.

For example, `seaborn.set_palette(seaborn.hls_palette(8, l=.3, s=.8))` gives 8 rather dark colors (lightness 0.3) that I believe will work well with projectors: [image: colors]

P.S. There is also a *dark* variant of the default six-color palette in seaborn. I have not tried, but I think it can be set by `seaborn.set_palette('dark')`

P.P.S. These color palettes have no effect on the background, though. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247866/3005167) answer may help out there.