# Changing sns clustermap x axis, label color to white

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've set my plot to transparent so when i access it after plotting,axis and labels looks dark
How can i set the label's and axis to "white" .??

I've tried this

```
import seaborn as sns 
DATA=sns.load_dataset("tips")           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                 
plt.figure()      
sns.set_style(style="white")
              
ax=sns.clustermap(DATA.corr(), 
cmap="viridis")

#ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
#ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
             
plt.savefig("clustermap",transparent=True)
```

Note that i don't want to change the ' background ' color, just the label and axis color

Comment: what is the format of the exported image? Not all formats support transparency. Try to use PNG: `plt.savefig("clustermap.png", transparent=True)`

Comment: It is in png format

Comment: I tested the provided code and I get a white background, maybe check that you have the latest version of the modules

Comment: I don't  want to change  the background color, just the label and axis color (i mean everything on the axis)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mwaskom/7be0963cc57f6c89f7b2, although I reckon you'll need to manually change the dendrogram color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use the seaborn.set() function. Here you have a previous answer:

[Setting plot background colour in Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238442/setting-plot-background-colour-in-seaborn)

Here you have  an example it seems to work in your case (at least in my environment ;-) ):

```
sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white', 'figure.facecolor':'white'})
```

to change just the axis's labels you can use this:

```
sns.set(rc{'ytick.labelcolor':'white','xtick.labelcolor':'white'})
```

There are a lot of very fine parameters to set your plot. You can review the full list of parameters just with the command:

plt.rcParams

You can get many details on such command in the link I gave before, going to the Joelostblom answer

Comment: I actually want to change the color to white for label and all the components on the axis

Comment: for changing color to axis labels try this:                                                     sns.set(rc={'ytick.labelcolor': 'white','xtick.labelcolor': 'white',})

Comment: I just changed the answer providing more details on how to change specific axis details such ad " axis tick labels", I think this is what you would like to change.

Comment: It works! , just gota figure out to do the same with the cluster lines